# how can click on recyclerview programicallity with specific text

Tags: android, onclick

I have a recyclerview in my project ,i want in my program if it show after one condition select the item with have text equal string : di and click on it automatically.i have below code that click on item with index 0 but i don't find code for click on item with specific text.

```
 mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to click on row with text?
You can do something like this in your adapter onBindViewHolder:

```
holder.SOMEVIEW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ....your code....

        }
    });
```